# Typescript import module to import minify version of js

Tags: typescript, web-essentials

When using Typescript (v0.8.3),  with Visual Studio + Web Essentials, I have configure Web Essentials to use the AMD module compiler flag, and also have it to minify the generated JS.

[image]

In my AppMain.ts I imported a module using the import keyword

```
/// <reference path="./../modules/jquery.d.ts" />
import main = module('classes/facebook');

export class AppMain {
    public run() {
        $(()=>{
            var app = new facebook.App();
            app.start();
        });
    }
}
```

And the generated JS looks like the following

```
define(["require", "exports", 'classes/facebook'], function(require, exports, __main__) {
    var main = __main__;

    var AppMain = (function () {
        function AppMain() { }
        AppMain.prototype.run = function () {
            $(function () {
                var app = new facebook.App();
                app.start();
            });
        };
        return AppMain;
    })();
    exports.AppMain = AppMain;    
})
```

My question is, how do I get the generated requirejs code to load the *.min instead? Since Web Essentials already generated the minify version of the JS file.

E.g. What of what I want from the generated JS file:

```
define(["require", "exports", 'classes/facebook.min'], function(require, exports, __main__)
```

Edit:
I've lots of modules, so I'd prefer a way that gives me less headache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend that you do not use these min files and use r.js for merging followed by a separate minification pipeline when you are using RequireJS to begin with.

It will save you headaches with debugging your app as well since you can easily debug the non minified ***js***.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add some RequireJS config to ask it to substitute the minified version of the library:

```
requirejs.config({
    enforceDefine: true,
    paths: {
        facebook: [
            'lib/facebook.min',
            'lib/facebook'
        ]
    }
});
```

Comment: I've for too many modules, I'd end up maintaining the requirejs.config for too frequently.